# Criar quadrado vermelho na tela - preciso criar um botão, onde toda vez que ele é pressionado, um quadrado vermelho é criado

Tags: javascript

Bom dia,

Preciso criar um botão, onde toda vez que ele é pressionado, um quadrado vermelho é criado na tela. Tentei fazer isso com o código abaixo, mas dessa forma o botão é gerado somente uma vez.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Criar Quadrado Vermelho

```
<script>
    var btnElement = document.querySelector('button.botao');

    btnElement.onclick = function() {
            btnElement.style.width = '100px';
            btnElement.style.height = '100px';
            btnElement.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
        
    }        
</script>
```

Comment: Você pode criar um elemento html e formatar como deseja com CSS (quadrado vermelho) e deixá-lo `display:hidden`. Quando clicar no botão, você muda para `display: visible`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Pedro! Vou tentar aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `document.createElement` desta forma:

```
<div id="meuDiv"><!--Aqui será criado o quadrado--></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()"><!--Toda vez que apertar esse botão criará um quadrado-->Me aperte</button>
<script>
function myFunction(){
    var quadrado = document.createElement("DIV");//crio uma variável para definir que o elemento será uma div
    quadrado .innerHTML = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";//crio uma tag H1(com "hello world" escrito nela) dentro da div
    document.getElementById("meuDiv").appendChild(quadrado);//pego o nome da div pai usando seu id("meuDiv") depois uso appendChild para criar um elemento filho dentro da div
}
</script>
```

Você também agora pode fazer com que tenha as especificações que você quer! Para isso você pode fazer no próprio css e adicionar com DOM uma class por exemplo, ou ir adicionando uma por uma com DOM assim `quadrado.style.(aqui fica a especificação css) = "(aqui o valor atribuído)"`.

Claro que não é remendado dessa forma. Mas tem uma forma melhor, que é adicionar esse código `quadrado.classList.add("minhaClass")` na função `myFunction()` depois adicionar em uma folha CSS suas especificações de CSS.

Comment: Muito boa explicação, obrigado! Eu consegui resolver, e agora estou com outro desafio rs 
Agora preciso trocar a cor do quadrado quando passo o mouse em cima dele. Vc poderia ajudar de novo? Tentei dessa forma e não consegui.

Comment: é simples no css coloque lá (elemento):hover{/*aqui ficam as especificações*/}
":hover" faz com que o css faça uma checagem toda vez que passar o mouse em cima de um elemento, no caso como você quer mudar a cor use um background-color: (cor aqui)

Comment: Olá, bem, existem duas formas que você pode tentar de novo!
primeira, no css: .quadrado:hover{background-color: (nova cor)}
segunda, no js: você pode usar onmouseout colocando-o no elemento ou em um addEventListener, crie uma função e dentro dela coloque DOM(elemento).style.background = "(nova cor)";
-
sugiro você dá uma estudada aprofundada em "css :hover" e "DOM" em js

Answer (score -1):

```
 <>
  <button id="toggleButton">toggle display element</button>
  <div
    id="square"
    style={{
      textAlign: "center",
      margin: "10px",
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      width: "100px",
      height: "100px",
    }}
  >
    square
  </div>
</>
```

jquery:

$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#toggleButton").click(function(){
       $("#square").toggle();
        });
          });